# Fiddling with wrappers width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to extend my wrapper, but it's not extending, and if it does it goes past that "X" button you see on the overlay.

Code:

```
#hire-wrapper { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    right: 140px;
    width: 900px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

#hire-content { 
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: #8E8E8E;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#888;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px #888;
    padding: 4px 0 0 5px;
}

.hire-right {
    float: right;
    width: 420px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

[image]

That green line is the wrapper, I'm just using that to see where the width stands. I'm trying to get that other box right next to it, but i'm having trouble and it has something to do with my wrapper. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/gkKa5/

thanks

Comment: Uh, 510px (left floated content, including its padding and margin) + 420px (right floated content) = 930px. Wrapper is only 900px so they can't be side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at adding a [`clearfix`](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) solution to counter 0 height floated elements.

I would also recommend adding a [`box-sizing`](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) style to all your elements so that you dont run into issues with padding pushing the width of content outwards

This should help with calculating exact widths of your elements should you want to continue with using float for your positioning.

An alternative to exact widths for your two elements would be to use something like percentage based widths for your internal sections. (This should also allow you to more create responsive sizing based on container width rather than hard coding each of the internal sides - but this is just a personal preference)

**Have a look at this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkKa5/1/)**

PS. watch your html tag closures (there were a few extra open tags in your code)